# Can't compile camunda 7.4 webapp

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, camunda

I have the following problem. 
I downloaded the zip file with camunda webapp project and imported it to Intellij. Now I'm trying to compile it but it doesn't work for me.

There is a problem with following part of pom.xml file

```
<version>7.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../camunda-bpm-platform/database</relativePath>
```

When I try to execute maven clean command, the command line says:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp:7.4.2-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\me\IdeaProjects\camunda-bpm-webapp-7.4\webapp\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp-root:7.4.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.camunda.bpm:camunda-database-settings:pom:7.4.2-SNAPSHOT in https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of camunda-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp-root:7.4.2-SNAPSHOT, C:\Users\me\IdeaProjects\camunda-bpm-webapp-7.4\pom.xml, line 10, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know, what can be wrong with it?

Comment: Would it be possible to share the downloaded zip? Will help us avoid the hassle of signing up at http://camunda.com/trial/download/

Comment: I mean I downloaded it from github https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-webapp/tree/7.4

Comment: And when I clone it from git it is possible to compile master branch (but then I can't deploy it because it says that it needs camunda engine - I provided but it is version 7.4 so probably that is why). But when I switch to branch 7.4 I can't compile it. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build the current 7.5.0-SNAPSHOT, check out the `master` branch. If you want to build the 7.4.0 release webapp, check out the tag `7.4.0`. The `7.4` branch cannot be built with publicly available dependencies alone.

Comment: On what url I can reach the app. I deployed it but on the main url  http://localhost:8080/camunda-webapp-jboss-standalone-7.4.0/ it displays not found error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I succeded with compiling but now when I go to url http://localhost:8080/camunda I get the error message No process engine found. camunda Webapp cannot work without a process engine.

I have engine-rest war deployed on my jboss server. 
Does anybody know what is wrong with it?

Comment: If the previous answer solved your problem, you should accept that answer. This post would better be asked as a separate question and should include more details about the actual error message.